# Installing sysklogd in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

I am required to install PMIPV6 protocol for my thesis.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 on VirtualBox, so in the process I have to recompile the kernel; this process has been completed.

The main problem was when I started to install PMIPV6 software, it required me to install a package `sysklogd`. After some research I found that `sysklogd` is not available in Ubuntu Zesty.

However, I found a website where I can download the original file and install it. But then, I was not able to perform any operations such as `/etc/init.d/sysklogd restart`.

I downloaded `sysklogd-1.5.1` from [here](http://www.infodrom.org/projects/sysklogd/)

I have installed it using the instructions given [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/sysklogd.html).

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: Does `sudo systemctl start sysklogd` work?

Comment: @George Unfortunately it does not. It gives an error Failed to start sysklogd.service: Unit sysklogd.service not found, but systemctl start syslogd works.

Comment: that means it's called `syslogd` perhaps that't why the `/etc/init.d/sysklogd restart` didn't work

Comment: @george /etc/init.d/syslogd didnt work as well

Comment: Ok remember that we have the newer `systemd` I believe `syslogd` can be found in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder but not in the `/etc/init.d` folder

Comment: @George Yes there a file called syslogd.service but when i try to read it, it was empty. I could not restart sysklogd service using that

Comment: If the file is called `syslogd.service` then retstart you will use `sudo systemctl start syslogd`